# php not returning value of false

Tags: php, return-value

I cannot get a false value to return here. A true value returns fine. What am I missing?

```
if ((count($this->_brokenRulesCollection)) == 0)  {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: unclear question, not enough code.

Comment: I suppose it would be a tad insulting to ask you if count($this->_brokenRulesCollection) *is* actually non-zero.

Comment: I'd rather see `return ($this->_brokenRulesCollection == 0);`, but is the variable ever non-zero?

Comment: $this->_brokenRulesCollection is an array of objects. I can force it to be 1 or 0. When I force it to be 1, I get no return value. 
Perhaps it would be better to ask what I should expect to be returned when it evaluates to false. 
If I echo out the return value on the calling object when the function returns a true value, I get a 1. Otherwise, when I echo out the return value I get nada. I'm expecting it to be 0 for false.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In PHP, `false` when converted to a string is an empty string, and `true` converted to a string is "1".

Use `var_dump` instead of `echo` for debugging.

Comment: Most obliged, Nicolas. +1 for the reminder to use var_dump. <slaps forehead>

Answer (score 0):

The code can just return `false` if the array `$this->_brokenRulesCollection` is not empty.

If `$this->_brokenRulesCollection` is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, then `count($this->_brokenRulesCollection)` will returned 1.

Comment: So, would it be better to test for empty instead?
Basically, I just need to know if the array has anything in it and if it does, it should return false.

Comment: Yes. Using `empty($this->_brokenRulesCollection)` would return `false` if `$this->_brokenRulesCollection` is not empty. `empty` cannot be used as in `empty(trim($name))`, which would return an error. Also, in PHP, `if ((count($array)) == 0)` can be written as `if (!count($array))`, and the code you reported can be simply written as `return !count($this->_brokenRulesCollection)`. For the boolean operators (`!`, `&&`, `||`), any value that is NOT an empty string, an array without items, an integer equal to zero, `NULL`, the string `'0'` is considered equivalent to `TRUE`.

Comment: (follow-up) In example, the expression `1 && "Not empty string"` returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

In conditional expressions (unless you use the type matching operators === or !==) any non-zero integer is equivalent to true, any non-zero length string is equivalent to true and conversely, zero or a blank string are false.

So

```
if ((count($this->_brokenRulesCollection)) == 0)  {
   return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Can be written as just:

```
return count($this->_brokenRulesCollection);
```

C.

Answer (score -1):

if you actually want to see "false", put the value in a variable before you return. as such:

```
if ((count($this->_brokenRulesCollection)) == 0)  {
    $value=true;
} else {
    $value=false;
}
return $value;
```

Comment: This is incorrect; there is no need to store the return value in a variable before returning it.